# How do I create a default everyday date dimension?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a line chart counting all the optins per date, however the only dimension that is will allow me to choose from have to be a date column on my source. The problem with this is it only chooses from dates that are populated in those fields with an optin date.

For example: I have 5 optins on 1/1/2019, 0 on 1/2/2019, and 3 on 1/3/2019
If I use this series and want to include another metric, 1/2/2019 will not show anything for that other metric

I just want a standard everyday series that counts every metric on a given day. The google analytics connection source has a generic Date dimension but I can not figure out how it was done

Ive tried creating a new column with everydate on it and trying to use that as a dimension without any luck

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a Time Series graph (of which there are 3 types) instead of a Line graph.

A Time Series will keep the days where no data is available unlike the Line Graph which only presents labels for those which have values in the data.

[image]

Comment: I guess I might have been confusing, and did not know how to post images to SO, I am using a time series chart, however the only available dimensions to choose from are columns that are a date field, if there was no entry for the date field I choose, it does not count the entries of my metrics on that date. I want the dimensions just to be a generic date

[link](https://imgur.com/a/eBRGtdL)

Edit, also if you could share how to embed images on here

Comment: Hi Eric. Apologies but I'm still not following you, an example of your data would be useful. I just tend to "snip" an image and then upload it using the image icon.

Comment: No you are being great, Im sorry I am not properly explaining myself. So here on this graph I remove the date dimension from that chart, what I would like is to set is the Count of the Metric I have there, but the dimension/x axis would just be default calendar days not a date range from my data
https://imgur.com/a/utYnW4g

When I remove the date range dimmension it defaults back to 2014, can I change that? Or is there a way to set window for this default date range if I cannot use the date range filter my users use?

Comment: Have you put a date filter on your report and set the Default Date Range to auto?